# Problem installing SQL Server on Win 7 with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, windows-7

I have Windows 7 box.
I want to install SQL Server 2005 on it.

The box has following programs already installed:

- Visual Studio 2005
- Visual Studio 2008
- Visual Studio 2010

I had SQL server 2008 which I uninstalled.

When I try to install SQL Server 2005, I get the following warning message:
[image]

If I click on "Check for solutions online", it says no solution exists.

If I click on "Run program", I get this error and SQL server is not installed
[image]

Please let me know if you have know of a solution to this.

Comment: What does the summary.txt file referenced in the dialog box tell you?

Comment: Suprisingly Summary.txt had the same error message as is displayed in the above message box and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

There are two folders in the installer - Server and Tools.

I was trying to install Server first, and it did not install.

When I ran setup.exe from Tools it installed.
Then I ran setup.exe from Server and it worked.

Windows 7 and Visual Studio installations did not have anything to do as I had speculated before.

Thanks.